# Rewrite rules in nginx

Tags: apache, nginx

I'm trying to implement nginx rewrite rules for the following situtation :

> Request xyz.com/abcd1.css should be redirected to another server with the same url and different IP

`abcd1 css` is a regular exp in form of `abcd2.css`, `abcd3.css`

Answer (score 0):

A simple location block with a rewrite rule can do that for you:

```
http {
    ...
    server {
        ...
        location ~* /abcd(.*).css {
            rewrite ^ $scheme://some.other.host$request_uri? permanent;
        }
    }
}
```

There are likely several valid regular expressions that you could substitute, depending on your exact requirements.

Relevant documentation:
[location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location), [rewrite](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite), [$scheme](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables)